# Access denied to API when running it in docker image using robotframework

Tags: docker, gitlab, robotframework

I'm trying to connect to an API in robot framework, when I run my code locally it works fine and I got the response,
but when I put my code on gitlab and run the job in a docker image, I got this error:

[image: error message]

The expected result is to provide an access token to use it in an another authentication API.

Here is the code I used to connect to it:

[image: my code]

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: This looks like a network configuration issue. Your container is not allowed to connect to your server. Contact someone in your IT about this.